# Differences between preterito perfecto and preterito perfecto + estar +gerundio

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, pretérito-perfecto

For example:

> He buscado a mi perro.
>
> He estado buscando a mi perro.

Do both mean the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ESPAÑOL (English follows)**

En español hay más tiempos verbales que en inglés, a veces con diferencias sutiles.
Usando tu ejemplo, trataré de explicar las diferencias entre 4 posibles acciones en pasado afirmativo, excluyendo aquellas construcciones más difíciles de entender (por ejemplo el subjuntivo o el condicional).

(1)- Busqué a mi perro. I looked for my dog.
(2)- He buscado a mi perro. I've looked for my dog.
(3)- Estuve buscando a mi perro. I was looking for my dog.
(4)- He estado buscando a mi perro. I have been looking for my dog.

En todas estas cuatro construcciones se establece una acción pasada y que ha finalizado.
En (1) se afirma sobre una acción del pasado, sin especificar más. En (2) se afirma sobre una acción del pasado, e implícitamente se supone que dicho pasado es reciente. En (3) se afirma sobre un estado (lo que estuve haciendo), e implícitamente se supone que se refiere a un momento relacionado con el contexto (dependiendo de la frase anterior). En (4) se afirma sobre un estado (lo que he estado haciendo), e implícitamente se supone que se refiere a un momento reciente.

---

**ENGLISH**

In spanish there are more tenses than in english, sometimes with subtle differences.
Using your example, I will try to explain the differences between 4 possible affirmative past actions, excluding those constructions harder to understand (eg the subjunctive or conditional).

(1)- Busqué a mi perro. I looked for my dog.
(2)- He buscado a mi perro. I've looked for my dog.
(3)- Estuve buscando a mi perro. I was looking for my dog.
(4)- He estado buscando a mi perro. I have been looking for my dog.

In all these four constructs a past action is set and finished.
In (1) it states on an action of the past, without elaborating. In (2) is predicated upon an action of the past, and implicitly assumes that the past is recent. In (3) it states on a state (what I was doing), and implicitly assumes that refers to a moment related to the context (depending on the previous sentence). In (4) it states on a state (what I've been doing), and implicitly assumes that refers to a recent time.

Comment: I heard that llegar + gerundio equals preset perfect continous. Llego buscando - I've been looking. Isn't it true? So is it the same as He estado buscando?
I thought Estuve buscando means sth like I looked for, as Busqué. But Estaba buscando - I was looking for.

Comment: Maybe you mean `llevar buscando` instead of `llegar`. `Llevo buscando` means I has been busy looking for (something/somebody). Or instead of busy it could be dedicated to the action of look for.

Comment: Forgot to say when you use `Llevo buscando` you need to add how much time: `LLevo buscando a mi perro 3 días` or `Llevo 3 días buscando a mi perro`. The meaning is the same as in (4), but in (4) you don't need to specify the amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference.

Estar + gerundio changes nothing having to do with the perfect tense.  If you say

> Estoy jugando fútbol

then you **are** playing...

> He estado jugando fútbol

In a perfect tense, the verb proceeding the conjugated `haber` is always in the past participle.

then you have been playing..

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of **present perfect simple and present perfect continuous.**

> We use the present perfect continuous to emphasise the duration of an action which started in the past. For finished actions we use the present perfect simple.
>
> **I've been looking for my dog.** (I still look for him now.)
>
> **I've looked for my dog.** (I don't necessarily look for my dog any longer.)
>
> ---
>
> **Present perfect simple or present perfect continuous?**
>
> We use the present perfect simple, not continuous:
>
> - if the action is finished and complete.
>
> **I've written a letter.**
>
> - if we want to say how often an action has happened.
>
> **She's broken her leg three times.**

In summary **he buscado a mi perro** y **he estado buscando a mi perro** don't mean the same.